# How to put <c:out> tag inside <c:if> tag?

Tags: jsp, jstl

```
<c:out value="${xxx}" escapeXml="false"/>
<c:out value="${yyy}" />
```

need to check the above two values coming from server side in `<c:if >` tag

is it possible to do in `<c:if>` tag?

expecting like this

```
<c:if test='<c:out value="${xxx}" escapeXml="false"/> eq <c:out value="${yyy}"/>'>
</c:if>
```

but it is not working !! can you tell me the right syntax

Answer (score 4):

Use `<c:set>` to set a variable in the scope. Its body can be a `<c:out>`.

```
<c:set var="escapedYyy"><c:out value="${yyy}" /></c:set>
```

Then you can test it like follows:

```
<c:if test="${xxx == escapedYyy}">
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like that? Printing No name when person.name is null

```
<c:out value="${person.name}">No name</c:out>
```

you edited your question, answer is yes you can ;-)

```
<c:if test="${XXX == comparisonParameter}">
```

is your checkup

Comment: escapexml attribute present only in c:out so need to use it inside <c:if > tag